# SQL How to select columns multiple times on one row based on value in other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a report based on four tables as follows:

```
Table A: Columns(record_id, contact_id, role_id)

Table B: Columns(contact_id, fname, lname)

Table C: Columns(role_id,role_description)

Table D: Columns(Record_id, date)
```

Query:

```
select d.record_id,d.date,b.fname,b.lname,c.role_description
from a,b,c,d
where a.contact_id = b.contact_id and
      a.role_id = c.role_id and
      a.role_id in('legal','finance') and
      a.record_id = d.record_id
```

This query will produce multiple rows as follows:

```
Record ID | Date   | Fname | Lname | Role | 
=============================================
1         |Jan 2   | Bob   | Smith | Legal |
----------------------------------------------
1         |Jan 2   | Jim   | Jones | Finance |  
----------------------------------------------
```

What I need to produce is this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
record ID | Date  | Legal User | Finance User |       
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | Jan 2 |Bob Smith   | Jim Jones   |
```

I understand joins and concatenation, but can't figure out how to get the 2 users on one row based on the role.

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately.  What database are you really using?

Comment: answer is very different for mysql vs Microsoft sql-server so which are you using?

Comment: Mssql.....shouldnt have clicked so many tags...sorry

Comment: I'm an idiot....long day...'from from'....sorry and thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       select d.record_id,d.date
          ,b.fname + b.lname AS name
          ,c.role_description + ' User' as role_description
       from a,b,c,d
       where a.contact_id = b.contact_id and
            a.role_id = c.role_id and
            a.role_id in('legal','finance') and
            a.record_id = d.record_id
    ) q
    PIVOT 
    (
       MAX(name)
       FOR role_description IN ([Legal User], [Finance User])
    )
```

You should be able to use PIVOT.  I know it seems weird because you are taking MAX() of a varchar but it works to do so.

Per your comment for your specific syntax that is not simplified I would go with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       select
          d.ctx_id
          ,effective_date,
          b.first_name + b.last_name AS name
          ,c.description
       from
          ctx_contract_contacts a
          INNER JOIN ctx_contacts b
          ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id
          INNER JOIN code_lookup c
          ON a.association = c.lookup_code 
          INNER JOIN ctx_basic_info d 
          ON a.ctx_id = d.ctx_id
       where
          and a.association in(117601,117759)
    ) q 

    PIVOT
    (
       MAX(name) 
       FOR description IN ([Legal Reviewer], [NDA reviewer])
    ) p
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, but must have messed up the syntax when adjusting for actual db values. I simplified to make the example clearer. Here is the error:

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'from'...... it looks right to me, but I probably missed a comma or something..

Comment: SELECT *
FROM
    (
       select d.ctx_id,effective_date
          ,b.first_name + b.last_name AS name
          ,c.description
       from from ctx_contract_contacts a, ctx_contacts b, code_lookup c, ctx_basic_info d
       where a.contact_id = b.contact_id and
            a.association = c.lookup_code and
            a.association in(117601,117759) and
            a.ctx_id = d.ctx_id
    ) q
    PIVOT 
    (
       MAX(name)
       FOR description IN ([Legal Reviewer], [NDA reviewer])
    )

Comment: from is repeated twice in your inner select.  Also I should note make sure that the exact value of the description column that you want are what are in the brackets.  And you should look into using JOIN syntax it is way better and more readable

Comment: I will explore joins. I saw the from from as soon as I posted my reply. It's been a long day and i can't see straight anymore. Thanks for the solution and have a great weekend.

Comment: no problem, I just posted a version using Joins in my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.record_id,d.date,
[legal user]=case role_id when 'legal' then b.fname +' '+b.lname
[Finance user]=case role_id when 'finance' then b.fname +' '+b.lname
from a,b,c,d
where a.contact_id = b.contact_id and
      a.role_id = c.role_id and
      a.role_id in('legal','finance') and
      a.record_id = d.record_id
```